# Show that $(y_1, y_2) ^2 = (y_1, y_1) (y_2, y_2)$ iff $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly dependent, where $y_1, y_2 \in E$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

In the [book](http://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4%E2%80%A6) of *Linear Algebra* by Werner Greub, at page 285, it is stated in a proof that

> Let $E$ be a n-dimensional inner product space.Then  $$(y_1, y_2) ^2 =
>  (y_1, y_1) (y_2, y_2)$$ iff $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly dependent.

If it clear that $\Leftarrow$ holds, but how do we show $\Rightarrow$ ?

Comment: It's not true: let $y_2=0$ but $y_1\ne0$. The equality holds iff $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Isn't the statements "$y_1 = \lambda y_2$" and "$y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly dependent" equivalent ?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Oh, I see that, just putting the scalar only one side make my statement invalid for your example. Thanks for pointing out, I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: Consider the norm of $(y_2,y_2)y_1-(y_1,y_1)y_2$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, that gives the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but in the book, the proof for "iff $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly dependent" is not so much elegant, do you have any suggesting how to show that  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That direction is the equality case of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.